# How can i pass style attribute in table in lxml

Tags: python, django

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import requests
page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-advt-no-17/31908/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
tables = tree.xpath('//table')
file = open("output.html","wb") 
for t in tables:
    print(etree.tostring(t))
    file.write(etree.tostring(t))
```

ex : table style="color:red;padding:5px;"
How can i pass style attribute in table in lxml

Comment: You mean in the `.xpath(..)`?

Comment: yes. using xpath

Comment: Then it is `//table[@style="color:red;padding:5px;"]`

Comment: and how can i do for class and id??

Comment: same but with `@class` and `@id`.

Comment: //table[@class="classname"]

Comment: is it correct??

Comment: yes, but you thus need to specify the full class string, and in the same order.

Comment: okk get it . Thanks bro. for helping me as always